# How to center a block element without knowing its width?

Tags: css

The code below works fine at 1280x800, however, if I add another thumbnail, the width of the `<ul>` becomes equal to the `<body>` width and `<ul>` isn't centered anymore. I don't want to specify the `<ul>` width, which would solve the problem. I want thumbnails to occupy all free space regardless of resolution, but at the same time having equal margins on the left and right. Is there any pure CSS way of doing this without calculating the `<ul>`'s width in JavaScript each time the page loads or using CSS3 media queries?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {
            text-align: center;
        }
        ul {
            padding: 0;
            display: inline-block;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        li {
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: violet;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>thumbnail</li>
        <li>thumbnail</li>
        <li>thumbnail</li>
        <li>thumbnail</li>
        <li>thumbnail</li>
        <li>thumbnail</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use lists, by adding the "display: inline-block" to li elements themselves

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Gallery</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
        text-align: center;
    }
    ul {
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        width:100%;
    }
    li {
        width: 200px;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color: violet;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>thumbnail</li>
    <li>thumbnail</li>
    <li>thumbnail</li>
    <li>thumbnail</li>
    <li>thumbnail</li>
    <li>thumbnail</li><li>thumbnail</li>
</ul>
</body>​​​​​
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, after pondering your problem I thought it was somewhat impossible. But then I realized you could take advantage of the way images are displayed and work within the browser. Try the following code and see if it works for your purposes:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {

        }
        div {
            text-align:center;
        }
        .thumb {
            display:inline;
            margin:5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="thumb"><img src="http://cvcl.mit.edu/hybrid/cat2.jpg" width="200"></div>
        <div class="thumb"><img src="http://cvcl.mit.edu/hybrid/cat2.jpg" width="200"></div>
        <div class="thumb"><img src="http://cvcl.mit.edu/hybrid/cat2.jpg" width="200"></div>
        <div class="thumb"><img src="http://cvcl.mit.edu/hybrid/cat2.jpg" width="200"></div>
        <div class="thumb"><img src="http://cvcl.mit.edu/hybrid/cat2.jpg" width="200"></div>
        <div class="thumb"><img src="http://cvcl.mit.edu/hybrid/cat2.jpg" width="200"></div>
    </ul>
</body>
```

You could, if you wanted to, even remove the container around the images. But it leaves it open for some sort of caption.

Comment: Good point, but I'd still like to use lists for semantics like in the example above.